# is it possible to generate a random mysql password with dockercompose

Tags: docker-compose

I am creating a dockercompose file.
I want to set up a project with this file. This dockercompose will generate 2 docker containers: One for mysql and the other for apache2.
What i want to do is to automated everything and i want to generate an unique mysql password. Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set a random password for mysql via the environment variable `MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD`.

#### MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

> This is an optional variable. Set to yes to generate a random initial password for the root user (using pwgen). The generated root password will be printed to stdout (GENERATED ROOT PASSWORD: .....).

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker#mysql_random_root_password

Docker Compose Environment Variables:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

---

#### Edit: Alternative Method - Env Injection

This is a sample alternative strategy that would allow you to use a random password for both MySQL and Django (or any other image).

You will need to install `pwgen` on your **host** system with brew, apt, or yum, and then generate a password setting it to an environment variable. You can rerun this anytime to change the password.

```
export DB_PASSWORD=`pwgen -Bs1 12`
```

Simplified `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_name
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user_password

  web:
    image: django
    volumes:
      - ./django_admin.py:/app
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
```

In your `django_admin.py`, you can now use the `DB_PASSWORD` env variable:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'HOST': 'host'
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example where the docker-compose.yml file puts the random password in django settings.py ?

Comment: I've added a second strategy to the answer that will generate a password for both the DB and the app.

Comment: You can now also crate a `.env` file where your `docker-compose.yml` is and in it you can save different environment variables.

Comment: after generation, to get the random root password at anytime during container lifetime you simply type `docker logs <CONTAINER-NAME> 2>&1 | grep GENERATED` ( [source](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker#mysql_random_root_password) )

Comment: Where should `export DB_PASSWORD=`pwgen -Bs1 12` be present? Should it be in build machine? should I generate it once and place it in a .env file? can it be configured during deployment?